# Using a Variable in a .query function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that takes the input name of a value in a column and that value will then be used in a df.query function. However, I cannot figure out how to make it a variable that it recognizes as the input.

This is what I have right now:

```py
def gettingWeeks(stateAbbr, stateName):

    stateCases = cases.query('state == stateName')
```

But it does not recognize stateName. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas `DataFrame.query` method expects an expression string created accordingly to its specific syntax. To use variables from the current name space you have to use `@` symbol before the name of the variable:

```
stateCases = cases.query("state == @stateName")
```

Should work fine.

Here is [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query).